# javascript convert array to json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got the following array:

```
array = [{"id":144,"price":12500000},{"id":145,"price":13500000},
{"id":146,"price":13450000},{"id":147,"price":11500000},
{"id":148,"price":15560000}]
```

i wanto convert it to json like this:

```
json = {{"id":144,"price":12500000},{"id":145,"price":13500000},
{"id":146,"price":13450000},{"id":147,"price":11500000},
{"id":148,"price":15560000}}
```

So than i can store everything in mongodb in a unique document.

Regards,

Comment: The second one would not even be valid JSON, so your question makes little sense in its current form.

Comment: The latter is invalid. What should the keys be? The ids?

Answer (score 0):

Just run a loop and equate...like...

```
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
  obj[i] = array[i]
}
```

It will do

```
{
 0:{"id":144,"price":12500000},
 1:{"id":145,"price":13500000},
 2:{"id":146,"price":13450000},
 3:{"id":147,"price":11500000},
 4:{"id":148,"price":15560000}
}
```

Because your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking

From array or another variable to json string =>

```
var str = JSON.stringify(thing);
```

From a json string to variable

```
var thing = JSON.parse(str);
```